Как сделать админом коллаборатора на гитхаб, чтобы иметь одинаковые права с создателем репозитория?
Я со своим другом решили сделать совместный проект и совместно над ними работать, вносить изменения вдвоём т.д. Для этого мой друг создал репозиторий на Гитхабе и добавил меня как коллаборатора на репозиторий. Проблема в том, что я хочу чтобы я с другом имели одинаковые права к репозиторию, и чтобы он не смог бы например, удалить меня с проекта без моего ведома в любой момент. Как сделать так чтобы я имел одинаковые права с создателем репозитория и возможно ли это сделать вообще? Спасибо большое.

сделайте админом третьего человека, а вы вдвоем будете равноправными кобелераторами

Если он владелец, то ничего не помешает ему удалить вас. Тут пара мыслей: 1 - если у вас есть опасения, что он может удалить вас — он точно друг? В целом, такое решается разве что юридически, составлением договора. 2 - для совместной разработки необязательны одинаковые права, и в принципе необязательно добавлять коллаборатором, можно просто пулл реквесты добавлять.
